# Ruby - Using Resolv::DNS to lookup DNS records through authenticated proxy

Tags: proxy, resolv

I have code that performs DNS lookups using Ruby's built-in `Resolve::DNS` functionality and it works perfectly to resolve IP addresses to names (or any other type of applicable DNS lookup).

It is working against our internal nameservers, however occasionally I would like to see what external DNS is reporting.

In order to bounce an IP address up against Google's public DNS (8.8.8.8 / https://dns.google.com/), for example, I need to be able to make requests through our authenticated proxy.

I have tried setting `http_proxy` and `HTTPS_PROXY` at the command line (using known good syntax that works outside of `Resolv::DNS`.  I have also tried specifically using `ENV['http_proxy'] = 'http://username:password@hostname:port'` (with both capitalization for the environment variable, of course).

Does anyone know how to make requests through a proxy with `Resolv::DNS`?

Please note that I have other code that depends on using `Resolv::DNS` so I am not looking for answers that attempt to leverage other Ruby gems/libraries for this task.

Here is my code that works when query internal DNS nameservers, but it will not work against Google DNS (it will just time out after a long period of time):

```
 dns = Resolv::DNS.new(:nameserver => '8.8.8.8')

 dns_ptr = dns.getnames('107.23.199.237') # logitech.com

 p dns_ptr
```

Expected Output:

```
[#<Resolv::DNS::Name: ec2-ip-address-and-name-of-logitech.com-in-aws.com.>]
```

Comment: Was anyone able to review this question?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Still hoping to find an answer here.  Thanks!

Comment: Your example code worked for me:

    irb(main):001:0> require 'resolv'
    irb(main):002:0> dns=Resolv::DNS.new(:nameserver => '8.8.8.8')
    irb(main):003:0>  dns_ptr = dns.getnames('107.23.199.237')
    irb(main):004:0> p dns_ptr
    [#<Resolv::DNS::Name: ec2-107-23-199-237.compute-1.amazonaws.com.>]

How is this different from what you are expecting? This is with Ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16) on Amazon Linux.

Note that DNS doesn't really have the concept of "proxies", you are just providing an alternative resolver, in this case Google's public DNS.